# Python Webscraping data inside double brackets? (JSON?)

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to get prices for a specific item in different locations across the US. The site has a text box where you can enter a state and it updates the price but the URL remains the same. In the Developer Tools the location changes depending on your input which updates the price. I'm trying to scrape the prices with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/equipment/detail/1255/0350140/7500lb-mini-excavator/').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    # Finding the equipment name and printing it

name_article = soup.find('div', id = 'equipment-catalog-page-container')

    # This pricing is based off of typing "NC" into the search box

equipment_name = name_article.h1.text
print(equipment_name)


for price_article in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'info--price'):
    equipment_price = price_article.text
    print(equipment_price)
```

and the output is:

```
7,500lb Mini Excavator

Online Rate: 

1 Day: {{RateDaily | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}
1 Week: {{RateWeekly | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}
4 Weeks: {{RateMonthly | toCurrency}} {{Currency}}

The displayed rates do not include the taxes or optional charges that may be selected later in the checkout process.
```

For reference, the HTML code from the developer tools for the pricing aspect is this:

```
   <div class="info--price" v-if="showRates">
<span class="ratesSubtitle">
 Online Rate:
</span>
<br/>
<ul class="menu">
 <li style="margin-right: 10px;">
  1 Day:
  <strong>
   {{RateDaily | toCurrency}}
  </strong>
  {{Currency}}
 </li>
 <li style="margin-right: 10px;">
  1 Week:
  <strong>
   {{RateWeekly | toCurrency}}
  </strong>
  {{Currency}}
 </li>
 <li style="margin-right: 10px;">
  4 Weeks:
  <strong>
   {{RateMonthly | toCurrency}}
  </strong>
  {{Currency}}
 </li>
</ul>
<small>
 The displayed rates do not include the taxes or optional charges that may be selected later in the checkout process.
</small>
```

On the developer tools screen, where it says {{RateMonthly | toCurrency }} there is a price (example: $1,125) and where it says {{Currency}} it says " USD". I can't figure out how to get these to display the actual price on the developer tools. After some digging, I believe this is a JSON response but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It would appear the document you're getting with `requests.get()` only has placeholders and some JavaScript code goes and updates those placeholders with the actual values (or possibly keeps them live once the page has been loaded). You'll need to make the call that the browser makes after the page loads, which you should be able to see if you watch the 'Network' tab of the developers tools and reload the page.

Comment: @Grismar Thanks for the response! I'm very new to python and scraping (this is my first project) so I'm not sure what 'making a call' would entail. Do you have a further explanation or more resources that I could look at?

Comment: With 'making a call', I meant perform a GET request to some remote procedure that the website makes as well to request the actual data. Similar to your current `requests.get()`, but to whatever the appropriate URL is. I can't tell you what the URL is, as the site you're referencing doesn't load for me.

Comment: @Grismar ok I am beginning to understand! I checked the network tab and the website is making 3 additional calls with the following URLs when I enter a new location into the search box: https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/ccdata/user/setshoppinglocation/ , https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/equipment/getuserequipmentviewdata/ , https://www.sunbeltrentals.com/ccdata/rates/getrates with the request method being POST. I am using Chrome, so that might be why the URL isn't loading

Comment: Nothing from sunbeltrentals.com loads for me in any browser, so they are either having trouble, or they refuse foreign requests for some reason (I live in Australia) - but yes, those URLs sound promising. I'd recommend trying to load them separately. If you're not getting the expected results, pay attention to the request headers you can also explore in the Developer Tools. I would also (opinion) recommend Postman if you need a tool to play around with web requests before putting them in a Python script.

Comment: @grismar Thank you for the information - you've given me a lot to look into. One last question though, the separately loaded URLs don't give me the expected results (it leads me to the sunbelt error page) what aspects of the request headers should I be paying attention to?

Comment: Typically, a header may have some fields that help the web server identify the context in which the request was made, so some session identifier, cookies, etc. Have a look at the request header and include the same fields when you make the request. You may also find that in requesting the main page, the response header provides some of the values the followup request headers need. Watch or read a few tutorials on http POST and GET requests to get a more in depth understanding.